# Power BI Use bar char to visualize units sold by store region name. My unit sold and region name have no same dimension

Tags: powerbi

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j070P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyKdl.png)

I have tried getting them together via Axis X and Y. But return value is wrong, Chicagoland should have 2 and Tristate will have 16. trying a few other DAX but unable to bring them to the correct value that I have needed.

'soldvia' is the table containing quantity information.
'Region' is the table containing region information.
'Quantity' is the column in the 'soldvia' table representing the quantity.
'RegionName' is the column in the 'Region' table representing the region name.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be either a direct or an in-direct relationship between the 'Region' table and the 'soldvia' table.

What are the relationships in your data model?